# Facing problems in creating a Timer in React Js

Tags: reactjs

`let [seconds,setSeconds] = useState(59) useEffect(()=>{ setInterval(()=>{ setSeconds(seconds-1) },1000)  })`
Passing {seconds} in html timer starts. But it works like 59-58 and then it is decreasing along with different numbers. I need solution for this.

I tried using loops and other methods but didn't work.

I was expecting 59-58-57-56 to 00

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that every time seconds changes your components gets re-rendered creating multiple instances of setInterval.

You need to wrap your `setInterval` in a `useEffect` in order to be able to clear it properly.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      seconds > 0 && setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [seconds]);
```